# How to make multiple conditions in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, algorithm, web

I have few conditions
there can be either 0 or more
I want to go through the array if there are conditions and create a callback function that I will call in the filter and override one parameter

```
$f = function ($value) use ($array, $key) {
            return in_array($value->{$key}, $array[$key]);
        };
        array_push(self::$conditions, $f);
```

I didn't think of anything better than putting all the conditions in an array and then pulling them out in a loop like this

```
 public static function isPersonСorrespondsRequirements($people)
{
    $result = true;
    for($i = 0; $i < count(self::$conditions); $i++) {
        $result &= self::$conditions[$i]($people);
    };

    return count(self::$conditions) > 0 ? $result : false;
}
```

in short, I want to get the result from the isPersonСorrespondsRequirements function, which will be compiled according to the conditions stored in the $conditions array and it will be called like this

```
$tmp = $array->filter(function ($value, $key) {
                        if (NeedMapper::isPersonСorrespondsRequirements($value)) {
                            return $value;
                        }
                    });
```

P.S. I work with laraver, cause function filter it is collection method

Comment: Could you give some data, conditions, and expected results as example.

Comment: data set:
An array of people with specialties, grades, roles, countries

all 4 or 0 can act as a filter at once

according to these filters, the IF condition is formed
in the format if (in_array($person->country, $array['country']) && ...))

so the number of in_array is determined by the number of filters

I want to form a function consisting of the required number of filters just once and just pass a person there as a parameter, and it will return true or false to me